# How Do I Play Video in ListView like FaceBook?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play multiple videos in a listview. Currently, each listview row item is a VideoView. This approach has not worked as the VideoViews act abnormally when I begin to scroll. How are apps like FaceBook able to play videos in listviews?

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly happens to the videos when you scroll them?

Comment: if i can implement the code in list view Adapter then it can give me response   only buffering.